# RTOS within an RTOS

Tags: arm, rtos, freertos

I'm planning to run an RTOS e.g Nuttx as a Process of another RTOS e.g FreeRTOS such that freertos tasks and the Nuttx running as a Freertos task would co-exist.

Would this be feasible implementation given that the underlying hardware is an ARM cortex A8 single core processor? What changes could be required if the implementation is not based on VM concept?

Comment: How would the scheduler of NUTTX used?

Answer (score 2):

Your requirement, in a nutshell, is to allow a GUEST RTOS to completely work within the realms of an underlying HOST RTOS. First answer would be to use virtualization extension, but A8 processor does not have that, hence will rule this option out. Without Virtualization extensions you have to resort to one of the following methods and would require a lot of code changes.

**Option 1 - Port your GUEST OS API's**

Take all your GUEST OS API's and replace their implementation, so that it mimics the required API behavior by making use of HOST OS's API's. Technically now your GUEST OS will not have a scheduler, and will be reduced to a porting layer on top of your HOST OS. This method is used by companies when they need their software solutions to work across multiple RTOS's. They would write their software solution based on an RTOS. When a customer comes to them with a  requirement to run the software on their RTOS, they would simply port the RTOS API implementations on to the customer's RTOS.

**Option 2 - Para-virtualization**

Your guest RTOS user and kernel space should both work inside the userspace of your host RTOS. Let us break the problem into a few parts.

**Handling Privileged Instructions**

When your Guest OS, while executing in "Kernel mode" tries to execute a privileged instruction, will cause an undef instruction abort. You have to modify the undef instruction abort handler of your host kernel to trap/intercept these instructions and act on them. Every single privileged instructions has to be trapped/intercepted and 'simulated'. There are some instructions that wouldn't trap but would need to be handled by modifying code. Eg. If your kernel code reads CPSR to confirm the execution mode, CPSR would say the mode is User mode. (This instruction wouldn't cause an instruction abort, so you could not follow the trap and simulate model. The only way is to identify, search and replace these instructions in your GUEST OS codebase.)

**Memory Management Unit**

If a privilege violation happens the Data Abort will be triggered to your host OS. It has to be forwarded to your guest OS.

**Interrupts**

You would have to replace your GUEST OS's interrupt controller driver with dummy SVC calls that would call into your HOST OS to setup interrupts.

**Timers**

You would have to modify your GUEST timer driver to account for 'lost' ticks when you were running your HOST OS tasks.

**Hardware Drivers**

All other hardware drivers used by your GUEST OS have to be modified to allow device sharing between GUEST and HOST.

**Schedulers**

Your GUEST OS scheduler now works inside (and thus is at the mercy of ) another scheduler (HOST OS Scheduler).

Comment: thanks for the info guys, there is one small detail i missed out while asking the question though - all my code needs to run in SVC mode, therefore no user and kernel space concept...

Answer (score 1):

It is feasible.
You need to separate resources: memory, timers, IRQs, etc. So that, "Host" OS (FreeRTOS) don't even "know" about resources used by "Guest" OS (Nuttx).

For Cortex-A8 you may want to use IRQ for FreeRTOS and FIQ for GuestOS. It will let you not to rewrite IRQ controller (but again, make sure Host does not control FIQ after GuestOS started).

And some changes might be required for context switch: you need to differ Host-Host context switch, Host-Guest (and Guest-Host) and Guest-Guest context switch.

Answer (score 1):

Though not direct answer to your question, address this problem at design level, do a separation of code that depends hardware (create API) and make the application level code independent of the underlying OS or runtime i.e rather depend on particular implementation let it depend on the API.

where ever needed port the hardware (OS) dependent code to the underlying OS/Runtime